# Reading properties in a sub class of AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, properties, spring-java-config

`Spring version 4.2.2`, I want to read the upload file location from a property file, tried adding `@PropertySource`:

```
@PropertySource("/WEB-INF/conf/my.properties")
public class MyWebAppInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Value("${upload.location}")
String loc;

...

@Override
protected void customizeRegistration(Dynamic registration) {
    registration.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement(
            loc, 2097152, 4194304, 0));
}
}
```

Didn't work

Tried this too:

```
@PropertySource("/WEB-INF/conf/my.properties")
public class MyWebAppInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Resource
Environment env;

...

@Override
protected void customizeRegistration(Dynamic registration) {
    String loc = env.getProperty("upload.location");
    registration.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement(
            loc, 2097152, 4194304, 0));
}
}
```

Is there a way to inject properties here?

Comment: My *guess* is that the initializer is fired off before the context initializes.

Comment: Have you considered loading the properties file using some variant of getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/conf/my.properties")?  It would surprise me (but I don't know for sure) if Spring tags work on servlet initializer classes

Answer (score 0):

Usually I declare the properties file using bean like this:

```
@Bean(name = "PropertiesFile")
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer placeholder = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    ClassPathResource[] value = new ClassPathResource[] { new ClassPathResource("/WEB-INF/conf/my.properties") };
    placeholder.setLocations(value);
    return placeholder;
}
```

After that just use `@Value` like you did.

Hope it helps .